# Path for dependencies

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

I have snippet of makefile

```
CXX      := -c++
CXXFLAGS := -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS  := -L/usr/lib -lstdc++ -lm
BUILD    := ./build
OBJ_DIR  := $(BUILD)/objects
APP_DIR  := $(BUILD)/apps
TARGET   := program
INCLUDE  := -Iinclude/
SRC      :=                      \
    $(wildcard src/module1/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard src/module2/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard src/module3/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard src/*.cpp)         \

 OBJECTS  := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

 all: build $(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
  @mkdir -p $(@D)
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
  @mkdir -p $(@D)
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET) $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

can anybody tell me what does the following line in snippets specify & how this path for dependency is generated:-

`OBJECTS  := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)`

Comment: Expression like `$(varname:a=b)` is known as [substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html). Expression `$(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)` takes `SRC` variable as a list and creates new list with transformed elements: each element is prepended with `$(OBJ_DIR)/` and its extension `cpp` is replaced with `o`. E.g. element `src/module1/foo.cpp` would be transformed into the element `$(OBJ_DIR)/src/module1/foo.o`.

Comment: Thanks You ! I go it :)